# Browser is crashing in CI after updating chrome to 100. I see error ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES in the browser log. We are using webdriverIO v6

Tags: google-chrome, testing, automation, cicd, webdriver-io-v4

Browser is crashing while running tests in CI after updating chrome to 100. I see error ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES in the browser wdio log. We are using webdriverIO v6 and docker. Selenoid to run tests inside docker container. Tests run fine if run locally. Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever found out?

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but couldn't find an answer online, so hopefully it will be useful to someone struggling like me.

As the error says, chrome is low on resources. The default shared memory limit on docker containers is 64mb, and newer versions of chrome need beyond that if you're doing heavy tests. The solution for me was adding updating the `shm_size` variable in docker.

```
    selenium-chrome:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
        shm_size: 2gb
        ...
```

I'm guessing the same update would also work for a `webdriverIO` container

2GB is quite a lot and I couldn't see chrome filling more than 100mb in my use case, but depending on what your browser is downloading, it might be different.

If that doesn't work check the memory/cpu usage on your docker container and update accordingly.